# Как правильно использовать большие(возможно) данные из android room бд kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Делаю одно тестовое задание, в котором нужно реализовать файловый менеджер с индексацией содержимого файлов и при каждом запуске проверять, что изменилось. Есть база данных, в которой храняться сущности:

`data class FileHash(@PrimaryKey val path: String, val hash: String)`

И я не понимаю, как лучше сделать эту индексацию. При входе я должен проходиться по всем файлам устройства при помощи `File("/data").walkTopDown().forEach {...}` а дальше по пути файла находить его предыдущий хэш из бд и сравнивать. И вот вопрос, как лучше получать этот хэш:

1. Каждый раз обращаться к бд и получать один `FileHash`
2. Получить и сохранить все записи как `Flow<List<FileHash>>`, как-то захэшировать path(пока тоже не знаю как) и обращаться уже не к бд, а к этой коллекции(потоку?)

Но я подумал, что во втором варианте может быть большой объем данных, с чем будет не очень эффективно работать. В котлине для этого есть последовательности, но что-то так и не смог придумать, как это правильно реализовать проход и по файлам, и по этой последовательности. Или уже сам возвращаемый `Flow<List<FileHash>>` является подходящим для работы с большими объемами?

Comment: Зачем вам вообще тут Room? У вас простое key-value хранилище, одна таблица в SQLite и Cursor в помощь чтобы проходить по списку.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, Это мое первое приложение, просто взял то, что было в видео. Но как я понял, это просто orm для работы с sqlite

Comment: У вас файловая операция по-любому будет дольше исполняться, чем запрос к БД даже через Room. Поэтому простое распараллеливание этих двух операций вполне себе решение для варианта 1.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, Спасибо) Пойду учиться распараллеливать)